# How to init multiple AudioHandler classes with audio_service - Flutter?

Tags: flutter, audio-service

How to initialize multiple audio handler classes using [audio_service](https://pub.dev/packages/audio_service)?

I can init one audio handler easy enough by calling the below in main:

```
  await AudioService.init(
    builder: () => MyAudioHandler(),
    config: const AudioServiceConfig(
      /// etc
    ),
  );
```

But unsure how to do this if I had two or more handlers. I assume this is possible as there is an example in the plugin readme that indicates you can, but I'm not sure how to put this into practice?

[image: readme]

Answer (score 0):

List them like this:

```
await AudioService.init(
    builder: () => [
      _audioHandler1(),
      _audioHandler2(),
      // Add more audio handlers if needed
    ],
    config: const AudioServiceConfig(),
  );
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this doesn't seem to be working for me. I am getting an error: "The return type 'List<BaseAudioHandler>' isn't a 'AudioHandler', as required by the closure's context." I have tried to cast as a List<AudioHandler> but that doesn't seem to work either.